# Unicode string format so Text is automatically split into Columns in PowerPoint Table

Tags: python, string, powerpoint

I am writing a Python program that formats text and copies it to my clipboard, so I can immediately paste this into a PowerPoint Table. I can do this for Excel cells - these simply use a Tab delimiter, so this was not particularly difficult.

```py
text = "cell1 \tcell2 \tcell3"
```

However, for PowerPoint Tables, I have no idea how to do this. The above actually gives me new lines in PP, not even Tab.

Any advice?

Comment: Python3 strings are Unicode so asking about a `Unicode string format` is the same as asking for just `a string`. Neither has anything to do with Powepoint or Excel though. What happens with Excel isn't what you think and has nothing to do with Unicode. For starters the sting you posted has tabs, defined using an escape sequence. When you use that string it contains tab characters, not escape sequences. Excel, and only Excel, will intercept the Paste operation, identify the tab characters, split the sting and insert each value in a separate cell. That's useful, because Excel deals with cells

Comment: Powerpoint, Word, Google Docs, NotePad, Sublime Text don't deal with cells though, so they don't need such a feature. Excel doesn't use tabs to separate cells. An Excel file is a ZIP package containing XML files, and [each Cell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.spreadsheet.cell?view=openxml-2.8.1) is stored in its own `<c>` tag. It's not the tab that makes values appear in different cells. It's a feature that splits the pasted string and stores each part in a different `<c>` element. The same feature intercepts styles and translates them

Comment: I can copy a range of table cells to the clipboard and paste them into a table on a different slide, so somehow PowerPoint is distinguishing cells in one or more of the clipboard formats it writes. My guess is it uses the HTML format for that because the Mac clipboard viewer shows not only the numbers in a matrix, but also the cell background colors and fonts that match the original. I think you need to use PowerPoint to copy a table range, then use your clipboard library to see which formats it writes to the clipboard and try to duplicate the one of those that best suits.

Comment: But you know what, I vaguely remember encountering VERTICAL TAB as a cell separator in some PowerPoint context, that might be worth a quick experiment. In Python, the ASCII vertical-tab character is `\v`. Also, it occurred to me that the RTF format could be what PowerPoint uses internally for copy/paste between tables, so that's something to look out for when you're looking through the formats it puts on the clipboard.

Comment: @scanny In Windows PPT, you can choose Paste Special; the resulting dialog box will show you what formats a) are on the clipboard and b) PPT is able to handle. In the case of  tables copied from PPT to PPT, it's HTML format (only).

Comment: Ah, good to know, thanks @SteveRindsberg that's a critical clue!

Answer (score 0):

Try HTML as @SteveRindsberg mentioned, either a row or a table. Best to consult the clipboard viewer for exact format for each of the cases. That would be something like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>cell1</td>
    <td>cell2</td>
    <td>cell3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Pretty formatting probably doesn't matter, something like this would work just as well but be harder to read for debugging or whatever:

```
<table><tr><td>cell1</td><td>cell2</td><td>cell3</td></tr></table>
```

You'll need to experiment to discover the general case; the cases I can think of are:

- whole table
- one row
- one column
- one cell
- multiple-cell "sub-table" that doesn't go all the way across or all the way up-and-down.

My guess is they all are expressed as a `<table>` structure.

Let us know what you find out for the benefit of others who later find this one search.